# Cosmos DB throws The input content is invalid because the required properties - 'id; ' - are missing Error

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to insert a JSon document into azure cosmos db, My Json document has and id column existing with string value. While inserting this JSONObject to Cosmos DB using CreateItem function but it throws error saying "The input content is invalid because the required properties - 'id; ' - are missing". Below is the code and sample JSONObject loading. Can some one help?

```
query = "select * from <ks>.<tn>";
Statement st = new SimpleStatement(query);
ResultSet rows = session.execute(st.setFetchSize(1000));
Iterator<Row> it = rows.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
if (rows.getAvailableWithoutFetching() == 100 && !rows.isFullyFetched())
rows.fetchMoreResults();
}
Row row = it.next();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(row.getString("[json]"));
jsonObject.put("id",jsonObject.get("doc_id"));
CosmosItemRequestOptions cosmosItemRequestOptions = new 
CosmosItemRequestOptions();
CosmosItemResponse<JSONObject> item = container.createItem(jsonObject, new 
PartitionKey((String) jsonObject.get("doc_id")), cosmosItemRequestOptions);
}
```

Sample Json doc:

```
{
     "abc": null,
     "year": 1996,
     "name": "",
     "num": null,
     "anum": null,
     "st": "mo",
     "did": "1398",
     "de": null,
     "sq": null,
     "dq": "",
     "d":null,
     "dpp": null,
     "dif": null,
     "dmf": null,
     "dtc": null,
     "id": "1398-48",
     "day": null,
     "dtc": null,
     "drt": null,
     "nr": null,
     "daf": null,
     "ds": null,
     "da": null,
     "andrf": null
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code and the JSON document you're trying to save. It looks like your JSON document doesn't have "id" attribute.

Comment: Please check if you have a id attribute in your jsonObject.

Comment: JSON has id attribute existing. Please see the sample JSON added in the question.

Comment: I noticed that there's an issue with your JSON document especially with `d` attribute: `"d":n\rull,`. Please change it to ``"d":null,` and see if that solves the problem.